# Buscador en tiempo real no funciona

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

> EDIT  con los ajustes de Rimuru Tempest

estoy creado un buscador en tiempo real pero me lanza este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo del buscador

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) exit('No se recibió el valor a buscar');
require_once 'conexion.php';
function search()
{
  $base = getConnexion();

  $h_list = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE StrNombre LIKE :search";
  $h_set = $base->prepare($h_list);
  $h_set->bindValue(":search", "%{$search}%");
  $h_set->execute();
  while ($h_res = $h_set->fetchAll()) {
      echo '

      <tr>
         <td>'.$h_res['Id'].'</td>
         <td>'.$h_res['StrNombre'].'</td>
         <td>'.$h_res['japanesename'].'</td>
         <td><a href="'.$web.'/cpanel/editar-serie?Id='.$h_res['Id'].'">Editar</a>|<a href="'.$web.'/form/del.php?Id='.$h_res['Id'].'">Borrar</a></td>
     </tr>


      ';
  }
}
search();
```

si añado `$search = $_POST['search'];`
me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si añado `$search = $base->quote($_POST['search']);`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este el de mi js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../admin/browser/brow.php',
      data: {'search': search},
      dataType: "html",
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#result').html('Cargando')
      }
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $('#result').html(resultado)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un error :(')
    })
  })
})
```

y mi archivo de conexion

```
function getConnexion()
{
  $base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=page;charset=utf8','root','');
  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $base->exec("set names utf8mb4");
  return $base;
}
```

en principio el codigo estaba para Mysql y no para pdo intente adaptarlo lo mas que pude

alguien tiene idea de como arreglar este error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizás debas intentarlo de esta forma. Por que quizás la forma en que haces la petición esta mal

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) exit('No se recibió el valor a buscar');
require_once 'conexion.php';
function search()
{
  $base = getConnexion();
  $search = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); // <-- falto esto xD
  $h_list = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE StrNombre LIKE :search";
  $h_set = $base->prepare($h_list);
  $h_set->bindValue(":search", "%{$search}%");
  $h_set->execute([]);
  while ($h_res = $h_set->fetchAll()) {
      echo '

      <tr>
         <td>'.$h_res['Id'].'</td>
         <td>'.$h_res['StrNombre'].'</td>
         <td>'.$h_res['japanesename'].'</td>
         <td><a href="'.$web.'/cpanel/editar-serie?Id='.$h_res['Id'].'">Editar</a>|<a href="'.$web.'/form/del.php?Id='.$h_res['Id'].'">Borrar</a></td>
     </tr>


      ';
  }
}
search();
```

Tu javascript debería verse así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../admin/browser/brow.php',
      data: {'search': search},
      dataType: "html",
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#result').html('Cargando')
      }
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $('#result').html(resultado)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un error :(')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Poes ya no me sale el error, pero no muestra los resultatos https://imgur.com/a/BUF784j

Comment: @Max edite mi respuesta, en tu javascript te falto añadir que tipo de respuesta se espera mediante ajax, al no especificarlo se esperaba que la respuesta fuera un JSON

Comment: actualice mi post

Comment: @Max creo que hace falta la variable `$search`(edite mi respuesta)

Comment: La función [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) limpia la entrada de texto para evitar injectar html en tu base de datos